# What is wrong in this .css ? (bootstrap, css, sidebar)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with labels in sidebars - they create a new line in left sidepanel

[Screen shot for labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPAiG.png)

They supost to be in the same line as "Approved" and "Unapproved" menu links.

> This example of code comes from : Bootstrap 3 Tutorials [COMPLETE] - Building a blog admin video tut for beginners part 6 and 7

.css file :

```
.box {
border: 1px red dotted;
}

#side-menu {
background-color: #2f4050;
padding: 0px;
}

#side-menu h1 {
/*color: #1f3647; */
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
margin: 10px 0px;
font-size: 24px;
}

#side-menu ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}


#side-menu a {
padding: 12px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #9fb1c2;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 13px;
display: block;
}


#side-menu .glyphicon {
margin-right: 6px;
}
```

.html

```
<li class="link">
          <a href="#collapse-comments" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="collapse-comments">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span>Comments</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="collapse collapsable box" id="collapse-comments">
            <li>
              <a href="approved.html">Approved</a>
              <span class="label label-info pull-right box">17</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="unapproved.html">Unapproved</a>
              <span class="label label-warning pull-right">10</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

If I change `display:block;` to `display:inline-block;` its better :
[Second screenshots for labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulrym.png)

but this time labels are little upper then they should be located. Another strange behavior is that articles label moved to left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `a` has `display:block` so its 100% width by default. `a` must have `display` set on `inline` or `inline-block`, like the `spans` :)

Comment: Change to inline and add :
#side-menu li {
 padding-top: 15px;
}
solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the `display:block;` into `display:inline-block;` that's working fine. could you please check it and let me know the solution.

Comment: Its different. This time labels are too high

Comment: Could you please provide the screenshot that will be helpful to find the issues

Comment: Of course, second screenshot is below my question description